# Exception when Spring Boot app to consume from RabbitMQ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have the following code in my springboot app

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow amqpInbound(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, "aName"))
                .handle(m -> System.out.println(m.getPayload()))
                .get();
    }
```

When I run start the app I get the following exception!

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'amqpInbound' defined in class path resource [com/mitchell/csg/acsstatefarmedibundler/filesHandler/FileMonitorBeanRegistry.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow]: Factory method 'amqpInbound' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper: method ()V not found

Here is my pom.xml.

```
 <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-integration-amqp</artifactId>
          <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
```

Am I missing any othere dependancies here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are mentioning Spring Boot there is no sense to override a version for dependency. Right now it looks like your Spring Boot version is not `2.1` which makes all the dependencies compatible with mentioned Spring Integration version.

Well, the simple answer for you is to remove a version from that `spring-integration-amqp` dependency and fully rely on the Spring Boot management.

Comment: I tried to update to 2.1 but i have other stuffs like
 IntegrationFlows.from(s -> s.file(new File
which are failing when I update it

Comment: You don’t understand me: when you use Spring Boot you typically shouldn’t use any versions for dependencies. Therefore don’t add that `5.1.0` to your SI AMQP dependency. You can’t stay on Boot 2.0 for everything else and just upgrade SI dependency

Comment: The ` IntegrationFlows.from(s -> s.file())` is from the old unsupported already SI Java DSL extension project. That was removed from the API when Java DSL was merged into the core project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-4.3-to-5.0-Migration-Guide

Comment: Thanks for the information,  was really helpful. I am quite new to this stuff. I am trying to read data from a rabbitMq every 30 min, can you please guide me on how I can use the pollable to do that, or if I have to look at some other way

Comment: Doesn't sound like it is related to the original question here. Please, consider to accept the answer for the current issue and raise a new SO thread for another one.